# Lowrance Sonar Pin outputs

Tags: wiring, transducer, sonar

I have this Lowrance fish finder [HDS 7 gen 3](https://www.lowrance.com/lowrance/type/fishfinders-chartplotters/hds-7-gen3-insight-noxd/) that uses a [HST-WSBL](https://www.lowrance.com/lowrance/type/sonar-transducers/hst-wsbl/) transducer to map the ocean floor. I wanted to use the transducer on its own with a Arduino. I looked into the pin-out of the fish finder to the transducer and only got some simple information.

[image: HDS 7 gen3 fish finder sonar pinout]

I was wondering if anyone has came across this before. I have a cut HST-WSBL, without the plug connector, if someone has a cut transducer plug please send a photo with a legend of what color goes where to double check the diagram so i don't blow up my unit.

Also if anyone knows anything about the connections of the Lawrance unit, please share your knowledge as it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `it would be much appreciated.` ... what is `it`?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You already found the pinout of the connector and the colors of the wires. What else do you need? BTW these transducers are almost certainly made by Airmar. You might find some more information [on Airmar's cross reference site](https://www.airmar.com/xref.html). Search for Lowrance and look for your particular chart plotter in the table.

Comment: I am trying to reverse engineer the HSB-WSBL so i can use it for my aurdino. I need the frequency and the voltages so i know how to power it. If you know any of this information it would be very useful. ( PS. what's the code for the HSB-WSBL )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei
Täällä näyttäisi olevan ohjeet tuohon asiaan:
https://ardupilot.org/rover/docs/common-underwater-sonar-analog.html

Comment: Please use english